# Base64Encoding of UIImage Doesn't Match

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, base64, nsdata

I have a `UIImage` and I want to encode it using base 64. I then send the string to our server.

Our server decodes it using `btoa()`. It can't do so properly.

After debugging, we found out that the result of encoding/decoding using `btoa()/atob()` does not match NSData's `base64EncodedStringWithOptions` when I convert from UIImage to NSData and then encode.

What's weird is they do match when I read the `UIImage` directly as `NSData` using `dataWithContentsOfFile:` instead of converting from `UIImage` to `NSData` using `UIImagePNGRepresentation()`

My problem is that I'm supposed to use an `imagepicker` that returns a `UIImage`. I don't want to write the image to file and then read it directly as `NSData`. it's not efficient. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for base64 encoding:

```
+ (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData
{
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] ;
}
```

Comment: The error still exists. I think something is going wrong with converting UIImage to NSData. Some data may be lost or something. Is there another way to convert the UIImage to NSData other than UIImagePNGRepresentation()?

Comment: Other is UIImageJPEGRepresentation.